# NetLogo: How to place a specified number of turtles in the coordinates (0 0) ~ (max-pxcor 0) in the "to setup ~ go" procedure?

Tags: netlogo

How can I place a specified number of turtles, i.e. 5 or 25 etc,, in the one-dimensional space of coordinates (0 or min-pxcor 0) ~ (max-pxcor 0) in the "to setup ~ go" procedure? Can someone have some ideas to this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, all you need is:

```
create-turtles 25 [ set xcor random-xcor ]
```